# What does this indicator on the ADT mean?

Tags: android, adt

When developing an Android project with the ADT then there is this indicator at the bottom of the IDE :

[image]

What does it represent ? And what to do if it reaches higher value ?

Comment: Not sure, but might be something about the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphic shows the values of the maximum usable runtime memory, and the memory currently being used. Often when you have a large number of projects opened and have ticked the

```
Build Automatically
```

setting, Eclipse needs larger and larger amounts of runtime memory. The current maximum memory value can be seen in

```
Android SDK/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

In the above file, the parameter

```
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
```

indicates the maximum size the heap memory is allowed to grow to.

When you click on the "garbage bin" icon, the garbage collector for Eclipse IDE is invoked, reducing the RAM usage.

Answer (score 3):

That indicates Eclipse's 'Heap Status' (Memory indicator).

You might have enabled in preferences.
[Preferences > General > Show Heap Status]

When you click on the 'bin' icon, it will invoke garbage collector.